# Can I solve this using p4 property?$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2x}{{\cos^2x + 4\sin^2x}}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2x}{{\cos^2x + 4\sin^2x}}dx$$

Can I solve this question using p4 of definite integrals

Comment: Well, there is only one way way to discover it: try.

Comment: And what is "p4", if I may ask...?

Comment: @Hans Landmark P4 : Property 4 of definite integrals . integral of f(x) With limits of a and 0 will be equal to integral  of f(a-x) with limit of a and 0.

Comment: @MarkHenry This property is known as the _reflective_  property. It must've been numbered $\text{P4}$ only in your notes.

Comment: https://youtu.be/wycadSRDID4

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
Recall that for any $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$ it is an elementary exercise to check

$$ \int\limits_0^{\pi/2} f(\sin x) d x = \int\limits_0^{\pi/2} f(\cos x) d x $$

Comment: It's a good observation, and you are not under any obligation to solve problems that are posed without any evidence of effort, but I'd say this brief note is more of a Comment than an Answer.  Of course a few more words about how to use the observation might well tip the balance.

Comment: @hardmath I believe the current [meta consensus](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28969/is-it-acceptable-to-leave-hints-as-answers) is that hints are acceptable as answers, especially when there isn't much work shown in the problem. I personally think this is quite a good hint, as it not only offers help in solving the problem while leaving some work to the asker, but also helps in solving similar problems. It's much more useful IMO than the "other half" of the solution would be, and certainly helps the asker learn more than a full solution would.

Answer (score 0):

Define $I$ as the original definite integral .Note that $\sin x=\tan x/\sec x$ and $\cos x=1/\sec x$. Use $\sec^2x=\tan^2x+1$. Let $u=\tan x$ and $\mathrm du=\sec^2x \mathrm dx$.

$$\int \sec^2x\dfrac{1}{(\tan^2x+1)(4\tan^2x+1)}\mathrm dx=\int\dfrac{1}{(u^2+1)(4u^2+1)}\mathrm du$$

$$\int\dfrac{4/3}{4u^2+1}\mathrm du-\int\dfrac{1/3}{u^2+1}\mathrm du=\dfrac{2\arctan(2\tan x)-x}{3}\implies I=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$$